# Apache Spark startsWith in SQL expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Apache Spark API I can use `startsWith` function in order to test the value of the column:

```
myDataFrame.filter(col("columnName").startsWith("PREFIX"))
```

Is it possible to do the same in Spark SQL expression and if so, could you please show an example?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following solution that works with Spark SQL query without custom UDP and out of the box, for example:

```
CASE WHEN instr(PRICE_SOURCE_INDICATOR,'MAC') = 1
```

Answer (score 7):

With regexp_replace, you can get the same results without UDFs. Check this out

```
scala> val df=Seq(("bPREFIX",1),("PREFIXb",2)).toDF("a","b")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: int]

scala> df.show
+-------+---+
|      a|  b|
+-------+---+
|bPREFIX|  1|
|PREFIXb|  2|
+-------+---+


scala> df.filter(regexp_replace('a,"""^PREFIX.*""","")==="").show
+-------+---+
|      a|  b|
+-------+---+
|PREFIXb|  2|
+-------+---+


scala>
```

or using regexp_extract()

```
scala> df.filter(regexp_extract('a,"""(^PREFIX)""",1)==="PREFIX").show
+-------+---+
|      a|  b|
+-------+---+
|PREFIXb|  2|
+-------+---+


scala>
```

Using instr() function

```
scala> df.filter("instr(a,'PREFIX')=1").show
+-------+---+
|      a|  b|
+-------+---+
|PREFIXb|  2|
+-------+---+


scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an UDF to do that

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
val startsWith = udf((columnValue: String) => columnValue.startsWith("PREFIX"))
```

The UDF will receive the column and check it against the PREFIX, then you can use it as follows:

```
myDataFrame.filter(startsWith($"columnName"))
```

If you want a parameter as prefix you can with `lit`

```
val startsWith = udf((columnValue: String, prefix:String) => columnValue.startsWith(prefix))
myDataFrame.filter(startsWith($"columnName", lit("PREFIX")))
```

**INPUT EXAMPLE**

```
+-----------+------+
|letter     |number|
+-----------+------+
|    PREFIXb|     1|
|    bPREFIX|     2|
+-----------+------+
```

**OUTPUT EXAMPLE**

```
myDataFrame.filter(startsWith($"letter")).show
+-----------+------+
|letter     |number|
+-----------+------+
|    PREFIXb|     1|
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: The parametrized example should probably use `lit(prefix)` instead of `lit("PREFIX")`.

Answer (score 1):

Spark 3.3.0 added the startswith function.

[SPARK-37520][SQL] Add the `startswith()` and `endswith()` string functions

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37520

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#startswith

Usage

```
> SELECT startswith('Spark SQL', 'Spark');
 true
> SELECT startswith('Spark SQL', 'SQL');
 false
> SELECT startswith('Spark SQL', null);
 NULL
> SELECT startswith(x'537061726b2053514c', x'537061726b');
 true
> SELECT startswith(x'537061726b2053514c', x'53514c');
 false
```